# TrustPilot Slider widget data-template-id

Tags: trustpilot

Where can I get the data-template-ids for the TrustPilot widgets available?
https://assets.ctfassets.net/b7g9mrbfayuu/4HuCkQtie4gGkwgWGIiou0/53edaddeee043cc10cccfcd21dea24ff/TrustBox_Cutsheet_20_08_2018.pdf

I am particularly looking for the data-template-id for the slider widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the data-template-id for slider finally - 54ad5defc6454f065c28af8b

Comment: `53aa8912dec7e10d38f59f36` for carousel

Comment: I have that same ID but still, get the error Uncaught No templateId supplied for TrustBox

Answer (score 0):

For anyone getting the console error: "Uncaught No templateId supplied for TrustBox", check that the container/div you added for the widget doesnt have a class of "trustpilot-widget". Once I changed that the widget was showing again.